# Alignment of equation using \begin{align}

Tags: amsmath

When I use the `begin{align*}` the equation starts in the red part. How can I start it in the blue part?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
Tex\\
My text
        \begin{align*}
        \color{red}x^2+2x
        \end{align*}
        \begin{align*}
        \hspace{-9cm}\color{blue}x^2+2x
        \end{align*}
My text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do I interpret your question correctly as not wanting to center a displayed equation? If that's correct, do you want to left-align *all* displayed equations? Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616012/5001) provided by @MarcelKrüger shows you how to go about having *all* displayed equation left-aligned. If what you need to achieve is to left-align just this particular pair of equations, I suggest you employ an `flalign*` environment, as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
Text\\
My text
\begin{flalign*} % <-- observe: 'flalign*', not 'align*'
  &\color{red} x^2+2x  & \\
  &\color{blue}x^2+2x  &
\end{flalign*}
My text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can request `amsmath` to align equations on the left by setting the `fleqn` (flush left equations) option: Replace `\usepackage{amsmath}` with `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}`.

This will still indent the equations by a fixed amount which can be changed by setting `\mathindent`. You could set this to zero to move the equations completely to the left, but I would recommend against this to make the equations easier to differentiate from regular text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% \setlength{\mathindent}{0pt} % Uncomment this line to get equations completely aligned on the left.

\begin{document}
Text\\
My text
\begin{align*}
  &\color{red}  x^2+2x \\
  &\color{blue} x^2+2x
\end{align*}
My text
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of editing your code to employ a single two-line rather than two consecutiy one-line `align*` environments.

Answer (score 5):

By use of the `nccmath` you can some `align` math environments locally align at  left border by inserting it in `fleqn` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    {\color{red}
    \begin{align*}
    y & = x^2+2x    \\
    z & = 2y
    \end{align*}
    }
\lipsum[1][1-3]
  \begin{fleqn}\color{blue}
    \begin{align*}
    y & = x^2+2x    \\
    z & = 2y
    \end{align*}
\lipsum[1][4-5]
    \begin{align*}
    y & = x^2+2x    \\
    z & = 2y
    \end{align*}
  \end{fleqn}
\lipsum[1][5-6]
    {\color{red}
    \begin{align*}
    y & = x^2+2x    \\
    z & = 2y
    \end{align*}
    }
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]